# Columns are not Recognized or in Index in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

So i am trying to groupby in my dataframe, and i keep on getting key error, column not found but when i do a df.head() i can see my columns

[image]

when i run my groupby, my column is not recognized
[image]

Comment: it could be leading spaces..try this `Profit(in millions)`

Comment: what does `df.columns` return? is it `'Profit (in millions)'` or something like `'Profit (in millions) '`

Comment: if you wanna `groupby` with multiple column, you may do it by `df.groupby(['col5','col2'])` that is `df.groupby(['Year','Profit (in million)'])`, did you tried this?

Comment: actually, i just realized it didnt work because i did df= df.fillna(0), once i took that out, i could see my columns

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strp()`

Comment: Solutions aside, I really recommend renaming those columns entirely to something which is easier to use in your code.